# VBA Converting column in table to array results in different types

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, automation

I am trying to convert a column from a table into an array and a range into a second array.

Using the same data (I manually copy/pasted) and having them in the same format of custom mmm-yy, I see they have different types once converted into an array.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Table1 As ListObject
Dim array1, array2

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

Set Table1 = Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("allDates")
array1 = Application.Transpose(Table1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)

With Wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    array2 = .Range(.Cells(2,1), .Cells(2,1000)).Value
End With

For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
    If IsError(Application.Match(array2(1,i),array1,0)) Then
        rest of code
    End If
Next i
```

`array1` is a 1d array, and has my dates as type Variant/Double. The value for 01/01/2017 is 42736.

`array2` is a 2d array, and has my dates as type Variant/Date. The value for 01/01/2017 is #01/01/2017#.

Since I have them formatted as the same and confirm they are the same dates/values, why does one array have it as one type and the other array as another type? How would I go about comparing the values?

Comment: `Application.Transpose` creates a 1D array. `.Value` of a multi-cell range is a 2D array. You should probably avoid using `Application.Transpose` for `array1`.

Comment: Also, side note, but `Match` is slower when looking in an array, vs. looking at a range.

Comment: @BigBen Yep, typo corrected. I mean I can access the 2d array as if it were a 1d array. Problem is the elements are of different types, thus my if statement will always be true (as there's no valid match).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `Transpose` or `array1` here at all, in fact, they're inefficient. `Transpose` can only handle a certain number of rows, and `Match` is slower when looking at an array. Just use the source range:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Table1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange

For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
    If IsError(Application.Match(array2(1,i),rng,0) Then
        rest of code
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The problem remains where `array2` elements are of type Variant/Date and when comparing it to the rng values, they won't match. I decided to skip arrays altogether and compare each cell with `rng`. This works. Very baffling as to why once turning the range to `array2`, the element types are no longer the same. Thanks for helping!

Comment: In some ways not surprising to me, dates can be troublesome. My only other ideas would be to create `array2` using `.Value2` (doesn't use the `Date` data type), or to use `CLng` on the `array2` elements if created using `.Value`.